# Some docker containers not reachable on LAN

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos, port, lan

I'm not able to connect to some ports of my docker containers and I have no idea why.

I can reach rutorrent on port 80 but not on the rest.
I can reach portainer with no issues.
I can't however reach the emby on port 8096

This is my yaml file:

```
---
version: "2.1"
services:
  emby:
    image: linuxserver/emby
    container_name: emby
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/Brussels
    volumes:
      - /mnt/storage/emby/config:/config
      - /mnt/storage/series:/data/series
      - /mnt/storage/films:/data/films
      - /mnt/storage/animatie:/data/animatie
    ports:
      - 8096:8096
    devices:
      - /dev/dri:/dev/dri
    restart: unless-stopped
  rutorrent:
    image: linuxserver/rutorrent
    container_name: rutorrent
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    volumes:
      - /mnt/storage/config:/config
      - /mnt/storage/downloads:/downloads
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 5000:5000
      - 51413:51413
      - 6881:6881/udp
    restart: unless-stopped
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: portainer
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - /opt/appdata/portainer:/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
```

This is my `docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                   NAMES
28d047c6524b        linuxserver/emby        "/init"             32 seconds ago      Up 30 seconds       0.0.0.0:8096->8096/tcp, 8920/tcp                                                                        emby
65e9be4b9b65        linuxserver/rutorrent   "/init"             2 hours ago         Up 49 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:51413->51413/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6881->6881/udp   rutorrent
f9210dc326df        portainer/portainer     "/portainer"        2 hours ago         Up 49 minutes       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                                                                                  portainer
```

`sudo iptables-save | grep 8096` gives me this:

```
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.3/32 ! -i br-1c6227ffc585 -o br-1c6227ffc585 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8096 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.3/32 -d 172.18.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8096 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER ! -i br-1c6227ffc585 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8096 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.3:8096
```

`sudo iptables-save | grep 9000` gives me this:

```
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.2/32 ! -i br-1c6227ffc585 -o br-1c6227ffc585 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.2/32 -d 172.18.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER ! -i br-1c6227ffc585 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:9000
```

When on the host machine I curl to port 8096 I get this message

`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

I hope you guys can help as I've been stuck on this problem for several hours. Thank you in advance

Comment: When you do your curl: what server do you ask for? localhost?

Comment: On the host machine is curl to 0.0.0.0:8096 which does not work. If I curl to 0.0.0.0:9000 it works